# Change labels in a barplot with a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, data-analysis

I know there are already questions about this, but my case is different and I don't know how to do it.

In my tibble there are a column "values" with a value for each observation, "ind" that divides the observations in two groups of equal size, and "average_time" that contatins the average of the group to which the observation belongs.

This is the code I wrote to get the graph:

```
my_data %>% ggplot(aes(values, x=ind, fill=ind)) + 
geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean) + 
 theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

And I get this graph:
[image]

Now I want to change the categories at the bottom of each bar from part1 and part2 to "Group 1" and "Group 2", but I can't find a way to do it.

Also, I want to add the average values in the bars. In other words, I want to display the value of each bar in white inside of the bar, something like this:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can provide some example data that we can use without recreating some ourselves. If `my_data` is not too big, you could run `dput(my_data)` and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ind, values, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean) + 
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun = mean, aes(label = stat(y)),
            vjust = 2, size = 12, color = "white") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2"), name = "Group") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
my_data <- data.frame(values = c(100.1, 52.5), ind = c("part1", "part2"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! Do you know how can I round the decimal digits? I tried to use fun = round(mean, digits=2) inside of the geom_text() function, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Use `aes(label = round(stat(y), 2))` inside geom_text

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the calculation in more than one layer, it might be simpler to precalculate it and feed that into ggplot2:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear = as.character(gear)) %>%
  summarize(avg_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gear, y=avg_mpg, fill=gear)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(avg_mpg)), vjust = 1.5, color = "white") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(
    "3" = "Group 3", 
    "4" = "Group 4", 
    "5" = "Group 5")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]